# General singular cubic surface consists of $6$ lines of multiplicity two and $15$ single lines?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subset \mathbb P^4$ be a smooth cubic threefold, $\{S_t\}_{t\in \mathbb P^1}$ be a generic pencil of hyperplane sections (so each one is a cubic surface, for smooth one it contains $27$ lines).

I read from somewhere the following statement:

> This defines a degree $27$ cover $\pi: C\to \mathbb P^1$ with $24$ branch points in $\mathbb P^1$, and over each of the $24$ points, the fiber consists of $6$ points of multiplicity two and $15$ single points.

I can understand the number of branch points $24$ is because the degree of dual variety $\check{X}$ is $24$. But why such fiber consists $6$ points of multiplicity two?

Everything is over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2703415/27-lines-on-a-cubic-with-multiplicity-contradiction/2704374#2704374

Comment: @Sasha Yeah now I understand this better. A general singular cubic can be assumed to have the form $f_3+f_2=0$, hence has $6$ double lines. But concerning about my question, I need moreover to know that if these are really branch points of $\pi$? Equivalent to say, let $S_0$ is the singular one $f_3+f_2=0$, and for all $0<|t|<\epsilon$, $S_t$ are smooth cubic surface, and we choose some $t_0$ near $0$, then the double line splits into $l_1, l_2$. Can we find a loop through $t_0$ to make $l_1$ go to $l_2$?

Comment: @Akatsuki if you have a map of curves $C\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ (of degree $27$), then your branch points $t\in \mathbb{P}^1$ are precisely the points where its preimage has strictly less than $27$ distinct points.

Comment: @loch But a priori I do not know if $C$ is smooth. So I think we need to determine whether it is a branch point by the monodromy. (Or, can you see it is smooth?)

Comment: @loch Did I make myself clear? I mean, for my understanding, $C$ is defined in two steps: let $U\subset \mathbb P^1$ be those $S_t$ ($t \in U$) contains $27$ distinct lines, so we have an etale $C' \to U$ of degree $27$. By Riemann existence theorem the unbranched $C' \to U$ and the monodromy information define uniquely a smooth $C$ and $C\to \mathbb P^1$. Therefore we really need the monodromy data: if the monodromy represent around some point is trivial, then the extended $C\to \mathbb P^1$ will have regular point there.